# Is possible to change desktop wallpaper in Unity? If yes, how to do?

Tags: 10.10, unity, desktop-background, usability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add new wallpapers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109208/how-do-i-add-new-wallpapers)

I've installed Ubuntu Netbook edition 10.10 on a new latptop for a people whit zero knowledge of how to use a computer.

Me and other people in our spare time are teaching the basics, like navigate with Firefox, email and concept like files, folders and desktop.
But I'm unable to change the desktop wallpaper... There is no right click on it, so how to change it?
It possible in a simple way to teach to this person?