# How do I add new wallpapers?

Tags: desktop-background

I have Ubuntu 11.10 installed and want to download and install additional wallpapers on my desktop.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 18):

You can "install" whatever wallpaper image you want easily by right-clicking on the desktop and selecting *change desktop background* from the menu

[image: Desktop context menu change desktop background highlighted]

and in the popup window, on the right side - where all the default wallpapers are listed - you'll find a <kbd>**+**</kbd> button at the bottom (where you click on), in the following popup windows you can chose from any folder on your hard disk any new picture you have already downloaded.

As for the "where" you download them, use your good friend Google.

Comment: That is ok if you have Ubuntu 12.04 Alpha release, Ubuntu 11.10 displays the wallpapers on the other side.

Comment: Wouldn't the solution be more complete and canonical if you had the "where you download them" part included. Google will lead them here and then they will have to do it again. Kind of redundant and rtfm

Answer (score 4):

[From memory:] Click on the Ubuntu logo in the top left corner and type "gnome-appearance-properties" in the search field. It should now show you the gnome-appearance-properties icon - click to start the appearance preferences with the background tab already activated. :)

Side note: in Ubuntu 11.04 you'll again be able to right-click the desktop and change the background like you're used to.

Answer (score 3):

Click the Applications icon in the sidebar, then search for "Appearance", then look at the "Backround" tab. (Extra clicks compared to the instructions above, but I use Unity every day.)
And on a side note, you can also add multiple wallpapers to the list of options by clicking add, then selecting all in the folder, then clicking "Open".  screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you are using 11.10, I would say that the easiest option is to find a wallpaper you really like on the web. Right mouse click and up pops a menu, it should say something like set as desktop wallpaper.  A window will popup and ask if you want it centered or stretched. When you are happy click ok.  Now your wallpaper will be stored in your home folder.  Something like firefox-wallpaper.png,  if you want to keep this wallpaper rename it and move to your pictures folder.

Now right click on the desktop and click on Change desktop Background.  From there you will see the appearance window.  Where the wallpapers are on the left in 11.10 and on the right in 12.04, click on the wallpapers dropdown list above them and choose pictures, you will see your images in the display window below.  Choose your desired image and viola.  You have your desktop image changed.

:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Compizconfig-settings-manager to assign a different wallpapers for each workspace. it looks very nice.

Answer (score 0):

I like to keep the wallpapers I ad in my Home folder to make it more convenient to share with my other PCs and so that I can move it to new installs. If you place wallpaper in the Pictures folder Ubuntu created for you it will be available in the Appearances Settings. In Appearance click the drop down list and you'll see your Pictures folder as a choice.