# Wallpapers of only some users being dynamically loaded in LightDM

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, desktop-background

As [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/64002/25130) explains:

> Ubuntu 12.04 Unity greeter has introduced selected user dynamic background, that means that when selecting a user from the available users list the background will change to reflect the selected user's desktop background.

However, I am puzzled, because in my experience this isn't consistently true. On one of my family members' computers, where there are three users, only one of the users' background shows in LightDM. None of the users are newly created. The user whose background is showing has a custom background; one of the users whose background doesn't show also does; and the other one who doesn't has the default switching wallpaper set. It is not a clean install but has been incrementally upgraded from about 8.04. Any idea what could be happening?

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129321/why-does-lightdm-only-show-a-custom-wallpaper-on-the-login-screen-if-i-have-sele/131921#131921) is a similar question, though we're also having the opposite problem (default wallpapers *not* showing). (I do not have access to the computer mentioend above at the moment; when I do I will use some of the criteria given there to analyze the problem further.)

Comment: The permission of the picture you are using as a wallpaper should be set as "READ only" for "OTHERS"..only then they can be accessed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a new box I had the same problem with a fresh install and a custom wallpaper that had all the correct permissions all the way up change of directories. I can't explain what was going wrong but what finally fixed the problem was when I set it as the wallpaper using the add (`+`) button in the Appearance dialog.

[image: add button]

Answer (score 1):

Was the system upgraded from a previous version to 12.04? If yes, then simply ask each user to re-assign it's wallpaper. Set a dummy one, then again the new one.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140910/unity-greeter-background-not-changing-for-users-automatically-after-upgrade) question was also posted about this

Edit:

Look for Bruno Pereira's answer [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm).
It's not the officially accepted question, but the one with 7 upvotes. He explains quite nicely how to set your own default wallpaper in LightDM.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! What about the one that is using the default wallpapers, though? The default wallpapers changed over the upgrade; thus, that user had to change his wallpaper. Is that because it is dynamic?

Comment: I've edited my answer..

Answer (score 1):

I found that if my wallpaper was not in the home partition then it would not be used in light GDM, like if had a wallpaper that was from a partition that was mounted using fstab.