# Unity-Greeter not showing personal wallpaper

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background, unity-greeter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add customized wallpapers so they appear in the dynamic unity greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123381/how-do-i-add-customized-wallpapers-so-they-appear-in-the-dynamic-unity-greeter)

I did a fresh install of ubuntu 12.04 64bit and for some reason my personal wallpaper is not displayed in the unity-greeter instead the (what I think is) default purple wallpaper is shown.  I have no idea what could be the problem and the people on the irc where not able to help me either.

NOTE: I know the command the set your personal wallpaper in unity-greeter, problem is that I'm using a wallpaper switcher and I thus want it to also always switch my unity-greeter wallpaper.  (I would be able to write a scipt that would been run every minute to reset the wallpaper but I think there should be an easier fix)

EDIT: I fixed the problem  I'm using wallch as my wallpaper switcher and stored all my wallpapers in /home/Backgrounds/  and I had set all my wallpapers to chmod 775 problem was that I didn't chmod the folder but I chmodded the actual pictures.