# How to set Default Unity Login Screen in Ubuntu 12.04 with Differant user background Screens

Tags: unity, login, screen, users, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add customized wallpapers so they appear in the dynamic unity greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123381/how-do-i-add-customized-wallpapers-so-they-appear-in-the-dynamic-unity-greeter)

Installed Pangolin 12.04 X64 with 2 users, one user has The default Unity  Login Screen with a different user background when logged in. User 2's Unity Login Screen is the same as there background screen when logged in. I want user 2 to have the Unity Login Screen with a different user set background when logged in.
This problem happened directly after installation. 
Have tried Ubuntu-Tweak and Gnome Tweak neither resolve the problem.

Regards
Ian Lester

Comment: Please see http://askubuntu.com/a/64002/63886 to determine whether it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Login to user2.
Change the desktop background of user2 session.
Logout user2.
On login screen try to see if it changes background as you change the user to login.

Comment: Have done as you requested, changed background of use2 and logged out.It tries to go to default login, but then instantly displays User2's background.

Answer (score 0):

i do not know the cause of the problem, but a simple solution would be to use a simple script for each user to set the background on login.  instructions on how to link to the script are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10797150/how-to-run-a-script-after-user-login-authentication-in-linux).  to set the background within the script, just use the /usr/bin/gsettings command (i.e. `/usr/bin/gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uril file:///path/to/the/pic >> /dev/null`)

granted, it's merely a bandaid, but may accomplish what you want in the short term.  if you need more help, let me know.