# How to disable changing desktop background (wallpapers) automatically in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, desktop-background

After I upgraded to the Ubuntu 12.04, it seems if I want a wallpaper, the only option is the default one, and the desktop background (wallpapers) would be changed throughout the day (once per hour). The problem is that it seems to be not very stable, especially in the case of using two monitors, it crashes during changing the wallpaper from time to time, quite annoying.

Is there a way to disable changing desktop background (wallpapers) throughout the day in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: The answer to this previous question might be helpful http://askubuntu.com/questions/123381/how-do-i-add-customized-wallpapers-so-they-appear-in-the-dynamic-unity-greeter

Comment: Also check out some of the related questions and answers on the bottom right of this screen while your waiting on someone to respond.

Answer (score 5):

When you right click on your desktop and select **"Change My Desktop Background"** (alternatively type **"Appearance"** in the **Dash**). You will see little Icons on some of the wallpaper selections.

These represent the slideshow you want to remove.  Select an alternative Wallpaper (with no icon) and this effect will be removed.  See my comments above if you want to add your own wallpaper.

For additional information the dynamic wallpaper slideshow wallpapers are driven by the contest.xml file hosted in usr/share,backgrounds

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I opened "Appearance" a lot of times, but I should admit that I thought there would be some icon on the left side to disable changing, I didn't notice at all that there is a small icon on some wallpaper.

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as the accepted answer, so it will help other in future

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use some other background. If you don't see the other standard backgrunds, click onto the little plus-icon and navigate to */usr/share/backgrounds*. There you should find all standard backgrounds.