# Adding Custom Wallpapers to 'Wallpaper' section?

Tags: desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add customized wallpapers so they appear in the dynamic unity greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123381/how-do-i-add-customized-wallpapers-so-they-appear-in-the-dynamic-unity-greeter)

Here is what I am doing:

Right-click on desktop > select "Change Desktop Background" > under the "Look" tab select "Wallpapers" from the drop-down menu > click on the "+" button to add new wallpapers to the selection > browse to the wallpaper and click "open" ...

What happens then is that the "Wallpapers" section changes to the "Pictures Folder" section with the wallpaper being applied to the desktop background - However when I close the Appearance dialog and reopen it and go again to "Pictures Folder" my wallpaper is no longer there!!

So ...

1. The Wallpaper should be added to the "Wallpapers" section and not to the "Pictures Folder" .... and
2. The custom wallpaper should not disappear -- ever!

And, yes, this is a clean install not an upgrade ... and yes it's occurring on other Ubuntu 12.04 machines as well - all of the 3 I have here.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. This is a site for asking specific questions regarding ubuntu. If you want to report a bug instead, you should go to launchpad.net and report the bug there. What you describe is definitely a bug, if only a usability bug. It is probably the one described here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/968268

Comment: The bug you linked to is similar but not exactly the same - at least my definition of it covers a bit more and seems more concise. Also I was hoping to ask the question first in order to see if there was an already-known solution for this ... I might just have to open a new bug as there does not seem to be anything doing this issue justice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding your wallpapers to the default location of the default wallpapers

1. Open terminal
2. type `gksudo nautilus` and provide password
3. Goto file system
4. browse to `/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-wallpapers`
5. log out, then in again and your wallpapers should be listed

If that dose not work try putting them in `/usr/share/doc/ubuntu-wallpapers-precise` (12.04 only)