# How to get Ubuntu version number on the Wallpaper?

Tags: desktop-background

I want to have Ubuntu Version name on my Desktop Wallpaper same as we have at login screen (LDM greeter) of UBUNTU 12.04LTS at bottom.

I want the same way on my desktop wallpaper on opposite side (left of screen). with same font and same style that unity-greeter has.

Anyone knows how to get UBUNTU Version name on Desktop alike UNITY Greeter ?

Any way to use UNITY-Greeter as Desktop Wallpaper ?

Comment: I want as UNITY-GREETER works.Its load text on user desktop Wallpaper Background same i want unity-greeter loads as desktop wallpaper. I dont want to use picture editor for this as any wallpaper loads i want that version name displayed

Comment: Any way to use UNITY-Greeter as Desktop Wallpaper ?

Comment: Yes have a look at this Q & A to understand how  http://askubuntu.com/questions/123381/how-do-i-add-customized-wallpapers-so-they-appear-in-the-dynamic-unity-greeter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got simple way to get the ubuntu version name to display on my desktop background.
For this I dont have to edit any wallpaper in Graphics Editor.Just installed the SLIDEWALL application.
Here is the link about it [SLIDEWALL APPLICATION](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/08/use-wallpaper-clocks-live-earth.html)

After installing the application i just gone through the codes how it works which is in /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/slidwall

Even the config file is in /home//.local/share/slidewall

What I have done is in /home//.local/share/slidewall/live created a folder name ubuntudsk and pasted the wallpaper i wanted.

then little editing done in gimp and created a logo of same wallpaper size with foreground layer transparent. and pasted this logo file in same folder.

you should look out the /home//.local/share/slidewall/live/ folder and  see the clock.ini file in it. Wallpaper should be of same exact size and logo file too.

you should created alike the same other folder of your own and create the same logo file with different name as it count in the copied folder.

What is done the app looks for the particular time,day,date image_name and paste it on wallpaper in it. So I have created as many as logo file with different file name and pasted over there.

So now whenever date,time,day change it just draws the same logo image on my background.

Try it.Below is how it works

BEFORE EDITING SLIDEWALL it looks like

[image]

AFTER EDITING SLIDEWALL i got what i want

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Anotherpossibility would be conky (http://conky.sourceforge.net/) which lets you place all kinds of information on your desktop. The only problem is that it is configurable only via editing a config file by hand, but displaying static text only is pretty easy.

Answer (score 2):

**One** way of doing this is to modify your background image in a graphics editor (Like GIMP).

You can add a text layer and place the text anywhere you like  on your wallpaper. If you use your background wallpaper dynamically in LightDM then you should also disable the LDM greeter UBUNTU 12.04LTS to avoid overlap.  You can do that here in

```
/etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf
```

Comment: I want as UNITY-GREETER works.Its load text on user desktop Wallpaper Background same i want unity-greeter loads as desktop wallpaper. I dont want to use picture editor for this as any wallpaper loads i want that version name displayed.

Comment: Hi AthloX:  I dont think this is possible and the 2 answers you have maybe your only options, but good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can edit that wallpaper and add Ubuntu 12.04LTS where ever you want in which ever font and style.

Comment: Buddy @Pranit-Bauva please review the question. I just dont want a wallpaper every time get edited. UBUNTU brand name must always there whenever i change the wallpaper.