# How to move my downloaded wallpapers to the default wallpaper directory

Tags: desktop-background

,I used a Newbie tutorial to download several wallpapers. The tutorial suggested that I create a 'wallpapers' folder on my desktop to store them. That worked fine, but now I want to move those files to the usr/share/backgrounds so they will show up in my default wallpaper list.

I've tried cp & mv in terminal, but neither works, and I get an error message the "usr/share/backgrounds" doesn't exist, though I can access it in Terminal. Could this be a permission problem, or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried "Sudo Nautilus" then copy and paste?  Also check this Q& A out http://askubuntu.com/questions/123381/how-do-i-add-customized-wallpapers-so-they-appear-in-the-dynamic-unity-greeter

Comment: @StephenMyall not the best method. Someone might consider that a very handy method and forget about possible problems that can happen when using sudo in a file browser (like flipping permissions to root on a file).

Comment: @Rinzwind Agreed which is why I also pointed the OP to the other Question and Answers where permissions are explained.

Answer (score 1):

The theme section you are shown when selecting properties from the desktop also has a drop down menu to select a wallpaper from the /home/$USER/Pictures/ folder.

[image]

This should be the most logical place to store pictures.

Nevertheless the command to store those images in /usr/share/background/ would be

```
sudo cp /home/$USER/Desktop/wallpapers/* /usr/share/backgrounds/
```

Comment: I consider it a bug that Ubuntu doesn't look in Pictures subdirectories.

I have over 700 desktop background images. I don't want them mixed in with everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it's to do with permissions. Just add sudo to your commands and they should work as you intend.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it may be a permissions issue. Try it with `sudo` and see if you have any luck.

If not, comment on this answer.