# Desktop Background doesn't show up on logon screen

Tags: login, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add customized wallpapers so they appear in the dynamic unity greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123381/how-do-i-add-customized-wallpapers-so-they-appear-in-the-dynamic-unity-greeter)

I re-installed ubuntu 12.10 and now this feature does not work.

Comment: Do you try changing wallpaper? Because when someone reinstall keeping home partition with user, that keeps the wallpaper, but not the logon screen. So, change for another one and then put it again that what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the desktop background by rightclick on desktop and change desktop  background

if you want to check are the pictures exist you can see this path : `/usr/share/backgrounds/`

then if you like to set another picture in this folder insted of original pictures you can copy your picture in this folder and rename your picture to the one of the original picture ...

it will appeare in you setting and if you like that this background that you have set appear on log in screen you should make sure that your picture size was the same as picture that you replaced .

if you have a problem with getting access to this folder you can change the permission of the folder by this command :

```
sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/backgrounds/
```

and this command works too : `sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/backgrounds/ -R`