# Is it possible to use a custom wallpaper in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

A few weeks ago, I was unable to set a custom wallpaper on my desktop. When I did, I was unable to log in because the login screen hung.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or deliberate, but I'd like to use a custom wallpaper on my desktop.

Is it possible?

Comment: It was probably a bug, you should be able to use custom wallpapers.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/109208/how-do-i-add-new-wallpapers - I have may laptop with a custom wallpaper I found online. As long as its a proper image format, I don't see why you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You can add your custom picture that you want to use as wallpaper by clicking on the "+" button as shown in the picture bellow.-

[image: Background selection]

And then navigate to the picture of your choice

Just make sure that the the immage you have selected is in any one of your folders under home and not in an external partition.